# csvファイルを辞書として書き出したい

Tags: python, python3

初心者です。
pythonでcsvファイルを以下のように値をリストにした辞書にしたいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか

```
'one','two','three','four','five'
```

↓

```
{'one':['two','three','four','five']}
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehension を使って、`with open('dat.csv', mode='r') as f: d = {r[0]:r[1:] for r in csv.reader(f, quotechar="'")}` などとしてもよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp/example.csv` を対象と仮定します。

```
import csv


def main():
    with open("/tmp/example.csv", 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        dic = {}
        for row in reader:
            k = row.pop(0)
            v = row
            dic[k] = v
    print(dic)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```